# Nested graphql query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am pretty new with graphql , I don't know how to apply this filter.

following is schema

```golang
const GET_TICKETS = gql`
  query Ticket($filter: String) {
    tickets(filter: $filter) {
      id
      title
      firstname
      lastname
      gender
      contactnumber
      email
      address
      pincode
      location
      emergency_type
      priority
      descriptionof_assistance
      date_created
      status
      work_items {
          id
          status
          service
          volunteers {
              volunteer_id
              volunteer_name
              status_of_acceptance
          }
      }
    }
  }
  `;
```

I want to fetch all tickets where workitems contain given volunteer

fetch tickets where volunteer in workitems.volunteers ....something like this

Answer (score 0):

When you use `useQuery` There is an optional second parameter  or `useLazyQuery` on the function trigger.

Example from the official documentation.

`useQuery`

```
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DOG_PHOTO, {
    variables: { breed },
  });
```

So on your case it should be

```
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_TICKETS, {
    variables: { filter: "the filter value" },
  });
```

and on `useLazyQuery` will look like this:

```
  const [getTickets, { loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_TICKETS);

  //..... somewhere else
  getTickets({variables: {filter: "filter value"}})
```

reference: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/

Comment: what will be the filter value, that's where I am struggling. I mean , how to write that filter

Comment: `fetch tickets where volunteer in workitems.volunteers..` you can just change the `filter` into something else that you want to filter for example, you want to get tickets filtered by volunteer_id, `query Ticket($volunteer_id: String) { tickets(volunteer_id: $volunteer_id) { ...` Of course you must provide the parameter on your backend Schema, and process it. It is unclear what is the precise filter you want, determined by your explanation